# How to store text lines from and arraylist into a .txt file?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have ran into a problem with my program. The bellow method is the part of my program that is suppose to store the text lines stored in ArrayList into a text file (e.g store.txt) what am I doing wrong here? The program compiles but it does not store the text lines in to the said file. Bellow is the said method that is suppose to store the text lines

```
// this part stores the string into a file
static void storeTextLinesToFile(List<String> listOfTextLines, String fileName) {
    try {
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(
                "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/zing/store.txt/" + fileName));

        for (String line : listOfTextLines) {
            outputFile.println(line);
        }

        outputFile.close();

    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.out.println("\n\n Cannot write to file \"" + fileName + "\"");
    }
}
```

Comment: does it throw exception ?

Comment: it does not do anything after printing out the arraylist text files

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: apologies @AndrewThompson

Comment: (Ughh) Fixing the things mentioned, is a *lot* more useful than giving apologies.  And besides that, there is nothing you've done that deserves an apology to anyone.  They are just tips. :)

Comment: While we are at it, the argument declaration is more general as "List<String>" than as "ArrayList<String>" :-) Additionally use try-with-resources to handle the PrintWriter (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: @CashVai I updated code in your question to be more Java-like. But I have one question: what are you trying to do in `"C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/zing/store.txt/" + fileName`? In your question you are saying that you want to store to `store.txt` but in your code you are trying to store it in file that is in directory called `store.txt`. If that directory doesn't exist then your code will have problem creating file inside of it...

Comment: Here how the program is suppose to work: 1- the program asks me to type in a text. 2- then the program prints what I have written onto the screen. 3. the program stores the printed lines (with the above method) to the given destination

Comment: Maybe I didn't tell this explicitly so will do it now. Code from your question works fine for me assuming that you want to write your file *inside* `store.txt` **directory** (since you are using form `.../store.txt/your file`) and this directory **already exists**. If this is not your intention then [subash answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20300944/1393766) should be correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It's runnable code. It shows the code you have above works fine. I just changed the file path. I'm running from NetBeans so the file ends up in the Project Root folder.

```
ProjectRoot
         src
         build
         store.txt
```

---

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StoreToFIle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        storeTextLinesToFile(list, "store.txt");
    }

    static void storeTextLinesToFile(List<String> listOfTextLines, String fileName) {
        try {
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));

            for (String line : listOfTextLines) {
                outputFile.println(line);
            }

            outputFile.close();

        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            System.out.println("\n\n Cannot write to file \"" + fileName + "\"");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use printStackTrace() in catch block. Then only you know the absolute error of your program.
and look here.

```
PrintWriter output_file  = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter( "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/zing/store.txt/" + given_file_name ) ) ;
```

Suppose `store.txt` is a file instead of directory, then you will get `FileNotFoundException`.
So try like this..

```
PrintWriter output_file  = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter( "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/zing/" + given_file_name ) ) ;
```

Give value to  given_file_name as `"store.txt"`

Comment: I did what you said still does not store!

Comment: @CashVai Do you see `Cannot write to file..` massage? If yes then add `ioException.printStackTrace();` in your `catch` section, run your code again and tell what output it gives.

Comment: @Pshemo you see it does not do that. It says "process complete" and that is it!

Comment: @CashVai I don't see any `"process complete"` massage in your code. It would be easier to help you if you post full but short code that we will be able to use to reproduce your problem. Also make sure that directory that you want to write this file to exists.

Comment: considering my bad code writing I wouldn't want to annoy everybody here by posting more bad code :D. The program gives the  "process complete" message after I compile and run the program which has other parts as well. Anyways thank you though! :\